# How to properly replace the deprecated setTargetResolution method?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I opened one of my old pet projects.
There's CameraX lib. Everything's fine. But setTargetResolution has been depricated.
`Deprecated use ResolutionSelector with ResolutionStrategy to specify the preferred resolution settings instead.`

It would seem that me just need to replace, as written in the tooltip, with:

```
.setResolutionSelector(
   ResolutionSelector.Builder()
     .setResolutionStrategy(
```

Some troubles.

If in setTargetResolution the size selection was

```
if (this.resources.configuration.orientation ==
      Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
          Size(height, width)
else
          Size(width,height)
```

Then in setResolutionStrategy I had to
change to

```
if (this.resources.configuration.orientation ==
      Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

And after that, if everything is fine at small resolutions,
then at 4000x3000 the error is:

`Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No supported surface combination is found for camera device - Id : 0. May be attempting to bind too many use cases.`

How to properly replace the deprecated setTargetResolution method?

Comment: Have you set a corresponding `ResolutionStrategy` as well? See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/resolutionselector/ResolutionSelector.Builder#setResolutionStrategy(androidx.camera.core.resolutionselector.ResolutionStrategy)

Comment: Yes of course I did it. `.setResolutionStrategy(ResolutionStrategy(if(this.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) { Size(height,width) } else { Size(width,height) },ResolutionStrategy.FALLBACK_RULE_NONE))`

Comment: You are using [ResolutionStrategy.FALLBACK_RULE_NONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/resolutionselector/ResolutionStrategy#FALLBACK_RULE_NONE()). As its doc mentions, if the size can't be supported with the current surface combination (depends on device capability), it won't choose any alternative size and throw an exception. And this becomes much likelier when you are trying a higher resolution.

How about using `FALLBACK_RULE_CLOSEST_HIGHER_THEN_LOWER` instead?

Comment: FALLBACK_RULE_CLOSEST_HIGHER_THEN_LOWER works wrong way. I set Size(1080,1920) or Size(1920,1080). And I never can get picture with this size. It falls back to higher size in any case even this size 1080x1920 available. FALLBACK_RULE_NONE works okey on not big sizes. Less then 3000x4000.

Comment: So 1920x1080 can be selected with FALLBACK_RULE_NONE, but not with FALLBACK_RULE_CLOSEST_HIGHER_THEN_LOWER?

Have you set an `AspectRatioStrategy` to the ResolutionSelector.Builder? If not, this seems like a similar case as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/328261422#comment2 where different resolution is being selected due to CameraX default AspectRatioStrategy being 4:3. Since CameraX prioritizes the AspectRatioStrategy more than the ResolutionStrategy, I think it's picking a 4:3 resolution higher than 1920x1080 when FALLBACK_RULE_NONE is not set.

Comment: `.setAspectRatioStrategy(RATIO_16_9_FALLBACK_AUTO_STRATEGY)
.setResolutionStrategy(ResolutionStrategy(Size(width, height),ResolutionStrategy.FALLBACK_RULE_NONE))`

BTW, if you are using CameraX 1.3, you also don't need to set the size in ResolutionStrategy based on device orientation and can use 1920x1080 directly (instead of having to use 1080x1920 for portrait). See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/308445386#comment6

Comment: 1920x1080 and 1280x720 are okey. But 1280x768 falls back to 1600x900. How to set AspectRatioStrategy for 1280x768?

Comment: In that case, you can simply set a [ResolutionFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/resolutionselector/ResolutionSelector.Builder#setResolutionFilter(androidx.camera.core.resolutionselector.ResolutionFilter)).

Then CameraX will pass all the supported resolutions to your resolution filter by the `filter(supportedSizes, rotationDegrees)`  method (sorted according to aspect ratio and resolution strategy, but you probably don't need to care about that) and you can pick the resolution you want according to your own criteria.

Comment: BTW, if your desired resolution is not among the `supportedSizes` provided by CameraX, that means the resolution is not supported on the device with the current stream/use case combination (unless there's some bug of course, in which case, feel free to report a bug with the CameraX team at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:618491&s=created_time:desc, or post in https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers if you want to discuss/query anything)